# How to disable implicitly-defined copy constructor generation when there is user defined destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Are there any compiler flags to enforce next rules?

> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy assignment operator.
>
> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is
>   deprecated(since C++11) if T has a user-declared destructor or
>   user-declared copy constructor.

I'm interested to enforce the rules in any of Clang, Visual Studio 2013 or GCC as the codebase will be compiled with all of them.

Comment: You could just inherit from `noncopyable`:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable

Comment: For VS you could activate "warning-as-errors"

Comment: @MarcoA. Is it a warning? In which version and at what warning level?

Comment: @EdChum I want to make the object copyable, but sometimes one might forget adding assignment operator/copy constructor

Comment: I'm not sure it's a warning but it should be. If it is, you can surely turn that on

Comment: @Marco On their [Explicitly Defaulted and Deleted Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx) page they explicitly mention that they won't emit a warning. Not sure if you can still force the compiler to emit one, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58407) mentions this test case which doesn't emit a warning in gcc:

```
struct W {
  int a;
  ~W() { a = 9; }
};

int main() {
 W w {};
 W v = w;
}
```

Refer to Johnathan Wakely's comment:

> That's not true, the compiler can (and does) warn about legal code.
>
> I'm confirming this, we will want the warning at some point, and it
>   would allow us to improve this part of the `-Weffc++` warnings:
>
> * Item 11: Define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for classes with dynamically allocated memory.
>
> (see [PR 16166](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16166)
>   for more details)
>
> Maybe we could call this warning `-Wdeprecated-special-members`, and
>   have it enabled `-Weffc++` and in C++11 also by `-Wdeprecated`

Clang already warns about this with `-Wdeprecated`:

```
main.cpp:3:3: warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'W' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor [-Wdeprecated]

  ~W() { a = 9; }

  ^

main.cpp:8:8: note: implicit copy constructor for 'W' first required here

 W v = w;
```

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx) explicitly states that Visual Studio will not emit a warning in this case:

> Additionally, the C++11 standard specifies the following additional
>   rules:
>
> - If a copy constructor or destructor is explicitly declared, then automatic generation of the copy-assignment operator is deprecated.
> - If a copy-assignment operator or destructor is explicitly declared, then automatic generation of the copy constructor is deprecated.
>
> In both cases, Visual Studio continues to automatically generate the
>   necessary functions implicitly, and does not emit a warning.

Comment: -Wdeprecated is good enough for me. I already have warnings as errors:)